# The constructor Adapter(HomeFragment, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) is undefined

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, constructor

I'm trying to populate a listview with remote data, I'm basing this part of my application off a tutorials code. In the tutorial they simply use classes, however in mine I'd like to use fragments as I'm also integrating a sliding navigation bar to the app. This is more than likely a stupid error on my part but nonetheless I could use some direction, thanks.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
The constructor LazyAdapter(HomeFragment, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) is undefined
```

This happens at the following line in HomeFragment:

```
// Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(HomeFragment.this, songsList);        
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

HomeFragment code:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    // All static variables
        static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
        // XML node keys
        static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
        static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
        static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
        static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
        static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

        ListView list;
        LazyAdapter adapter;

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blog, container, false);



            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
            // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
                map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
                map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
                map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
                map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsList.add(map);
            }


            list=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);

            // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(HomeFragment.this, songsList);        
            list.setAdapter(adapter);


            // Click event for single list row
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {


                }
            });     
        }   
    }
```

And the ListAdapters code:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(HomeFragment.KEY_TITLE));
        artist.setText(song.get(HomeFragment.KEY_ARTIST));
        duration.setText(song.get(HomeFragment.KEY_DURATION));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(HomeFragment.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
adapter=new LazyAdapter(HomeFragment.this, songsList);
```

to

```
adapter=new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);
```

`public final Activity getActivity ()`

Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

Also change

```
list=(ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

to

```
list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Also make sure you are doing network related operation on a bakgroud thread.

```
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
```

Edit : Missing return statement in `onCreateView`

```
       });    
    return rootView;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. But now I'm getting the following error: This method must return a result of type View. On this line of HomeFragment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Comment: @SeánNolan and missing a return statement.     `});    
        return rootView;
    } `

Comment: I've edited my above comment with the correct error thats shown. As for "stack trace", you've lost me altogether.

Comment: @SeánNolan i asked you to check the edited answer. and if your app crashes you need to post stacktrace (logcat) for further help. the error is pretty clear you do not return view `public View onCreateView` what is the return type for onCreateView?

Comment: I tried adding });return rootView; } This removes errors but still crashes when I try to run it in AVD

Comment: @SeánNolan a crash means useful regarding crash is logged in logcat. post the same here. i suspect `NetworOnMainThreadException`. A crash is different from syntax error.

Comment: You're totally right, good call! 12-08 14:23:47.657: E/AndroidRuntime(553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ngs.absractagency/com.ngs.absractagency.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-08 14:23:47.657: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)

Comment: @SeánNolan so use a asynctask or a thread to do your network related operation ie getting xml from the server

Comment: I took the the lazy route and used 'if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
       StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
       StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
   }'

Comment: @SeánNolan that is not the way. that is for testing only. use a thread or asynctask